# Multiple contexts , create only if not exists

Tags: ios, sockets, core-data

I have a view controller that is performing an afnetworking request , and upon the response , I am adding that response to my main MOC , and saving it. 
My app is a realtime app , and so , performing certain kinds of requests will send messages from server to client via a long lived web socket. What happens is ,when a client sends a single message , he will receive the same message via socket (and I am going to add apns functionality later on, so he will receive the same functionality via apns as well)

I want the web socket to use a background context, so my UI is taxed less. 
Right now I am performing a fetch to see if data already exists. If it does not, then I am adding to the context. This check is being done on the socket side as well as the api side.

My concern is , since they are both going to be checked at such close time intervals to each other, is it possible for them to both say that data doesn't exist, and then both will add to the db, causing an unwanted duplicate?

This is my code for clarification:

```
if ([Chat fetchById:[jsonBody valueForKey:@"id"] withContext:self.managedObjectContext]==nil) {
        NSLog(@"GOT NIL FROM SOCKET");

        Chat *chat = [Chat initWithContext:self.managedObjectContext];
        chat.id = [jsonBody valueForKey:@"id"];
        chat.body = [jsonBody valueForKey:@"body"];

        chat.user = [User fetchByID:[jsonBody valueForKey:@"user_id"] inContext:self.managedObjectContext];
        NSString *date = [jsonBody valueForKey:@"created_at"];
        chat.created_at = [TimeFormatter NSDateFromServerString:date];

        chat.group = [Group fetchByID:[jsonBody valueForKey:@"grp_id"] inContext:self.managedObjectContext];

        [self.managedObjectContext save:nil];
    }
```

Comment: What do you mean socket side and API side?

Comment: I'm using socket rocket as a web socket client. By socket side I mean inside the didreceivemessage function and by API side I mean the success block of afnetworking